# Gmail theme on Google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

For work I need the subject of all of my emails to be inserted into a Google sheet one by one. I've tried several scripts and none of them have worked so far. I don't understand how JavaScript works, can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the code you've tried?

Comment: Added code in topic

Answer (score 0):

```
function getEmails_(q) {
  sh0.clear();
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getPlainBody(), [msgs[j].getSubject(), [msgs[j].getDate(), [msgs[j].getTo(), [msgs[j].getFrom()

            ]]]]]);
        }
    }
    return emails;

}

function appendData_(sh0, array2d) {
    sh0.getRange(sh0.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
    var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(sh0, array2d);
    }}
```